How to force event handler to take precedence?
I have JavaScript code, in which I change the input field css class on invalid event to add an error class to a parent div having the class form-row.
I furthermore attach then an event listener on the form fields fields on input and click to remove the error class once the user interacts with the form fields (text, textarea, dropdown select boxes, ...)
Now, those form fields already have event handlers attached, and some stop event propagation.
Certain elements won't call formElementRow.classList.remove('error'); as some other event handler acts first.
Is there a quick way to force my event handler that I define here to take precdence while still allowing the other event handlers to act on the page?
I control the html of the form, I do not want to change anything with the code that registers the other event handlers.
This is my code that works for all my form elements except those who stop the event propagation:
const formErrorStatesOnBrowserSideValidation = () => {
    const targetClass = '.form-row';
    document.addEventListener('invalid', (invalidEvent) => {
        const {target} = invalidEvent;
        const formElementRow = target.closest(targetClass);

        if (formElementRow) {
            formElementRow.classList.add('error');
        }

        ['input', 'click'].forEach(event => {
            // some elements have other js / jQuery applied to them that stops event propagation hence the class removal is never called to those
            target.addEventListener(event, () => {
                formElementRow.classList.remove('error');
            });
        });
    }, true);
};
formErrorStatesOnBrowserSideValidation();


This is a follow-up question from: What event to listen for when a user clicks submit button in html5 invalid form?

Why not just use CSS and save a lot of hassle? Specifically, use the :has(:user-invalid) on the container to change its properties if it contains an invalid input. Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/3xpL95ha/. Click the Submit button to see it in action

@RoryMcCrossan Fair point. Not usable for me as the frontend browser validation should look similar to the backend validation in order to not confuse our users, and I want to execute further js

Depending on what your error states look like, that should still be possible. I'd even argue that your effort would be better spent modifying your server-side generated error notifications to work with the above approach as it's more semantic, and most likely more reliable

@RoryMcCrossan I understand, and please do post your approach as an answer. The scope of my question is different though.

Appreciated, but I don't believe it's a direct answer to your question so I haven't posted it as an answer. Merely an alternative which may help you in future if it cannot be applied to your current use case.,

@RoryMcCrossan And that is why I see your comment as an answer, as for others having my use case, for those your approach would be the better one. Not everybody reads comments.

those form fields already have event handlers attached, and some stop event propagation Event.stopPropagation will not stop the listeners for the same events added to the same element from being called, it will stop those for the parent(s), only Event.stopImmediatePropagation stop those added to the same element.

I strongly suggest an event delegation from the form to not have an event listener on each field

@Titus I have exactly the use case that I want a parent to catch the bubbled-up event. I don't want to attach the event handler on the same element.

@mplungjan Why? The input / click / change events happen only on one specific field at a time when the user interacts with the form. What is the downside of having "an event listener on each field" as compared to one on the form?

@k0pernikus Delegation is generally preferred but individual listeners may be justified if the form has very few fields or you need specialised handling that differs between fields. In most cases, a single, delegated listener on the form is more efficient and maintainable.

Since the OP seems to have to handle an environment where event-listeners are attached with a true value for the addEventListener's third usecapture's parameter, the OP has to handle each form-control's invalid event/state at the most convenient parent level of all the effected form-controls, preferably the form-element itself and not necessarily at document-level.
At such a parent level it does not matter whether any of the event-handler's, the OP is not in control of, prevents the propagation of an invalid event-type; rather the other way around, the OP could prevent the invalid-event from reaching its targeted handlers for every subscribed form-control.


function handleInvalidControl (evt) {

  // - none of the below three lines does interfer with the event
  //   handling of any other invalid form-control because each
  //   invalid control dispatches its invalid event separately.
  //
  evt.cancleBubble = true;
  evt.stopPropagation();
  evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
  
  console.log('control ...', {
    target: evt.target,
    currentTarget: evt.currentTarget,
  });
}
document
  .querySelectorAll('[type="text"]')
  .forEach(control =>
    control.addEventListener('invalid', handleInvalidControl, true)
  );

document
  .forms[0]
  .addEventListener('invalid', evt => {

    // - if invoked, it will stop the propagation
    //   towards any effected form-control
    //
    // evt.stopPropagation();

    console.log('form ...', {
      target: evt.target,
      currentTarget: evt.currentTarget,
    });

  }, true);

document
  .forms[0]
  .addEventListener('submit', evt => {

    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.currentTarget.reset();

    console.clear();
  });
body { margin: 0; }
form { width: 44%; }
label { display: block; margin: 8px 0; }
.as-console-wrapper { left: auto!important; top: 8px; width: 56%; min-height: 100%; }
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>validation test</legend>
    <label>
      <span>No digits</span>
      <input type="text" pattern="\D+" required />
    </label>
    <label>
      <span>No word characters</span>
      <input type="text" pattern="[\W+]+" required />
    </label>
  </fieldset>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>



